# How to correctly run code after a function has been completely executed in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-3

I am using a fullscreen CSS-preloader that should be removed completely from the site once the window has been completely loaded **AND** the function `checkRetinaHeader()` has been fully executed. The site is running on jQuery v3.1.0.

The code works on all major browsers, but fails on IE11 and lower on first load, when the site has not been cached yet (error: Script 5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference). In that case the code inside `.done(function() { ... }` is never executed and the CSS-preloader keeps loading. If you reload the page, i.e. the site is in cache, it works.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

  // wait until checkRetinaHeader() has been executed
  $.when( checkRetinaHeader() ).done(function() {

    var src = $('.header-section').css('background-image');

    var url = src.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1].replace(/('|")/g,'');

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
      removePreloader();
    };

    img.src = url;

    // removes function if background image has been completely loaded
    if (img.complete) img.onload();

  });

});


function checkRetinaHeader() {
   // checks window width and pixel density to load appropriate background image 
}

function removePreloader() {
   // hides fullscreen preloader overlay from document
}
```

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: From the error you're getting, and the fact that the callback isn't executed at all when the error occurs, the error seems to be somewhere else completely, than in the posted code ?

Comment: Try `window.onload = function() ...` in I.E instead of `$(window).on('load', function() ....`

Comment: @Tibrogargan - can you tell us what the difference is, and why that would work ?

Comment: @adeneo If I knew for sure I would have posted it as an answer.  The [JQuery load event docs](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) say it's buggy for images and since this code uses load events for images it might be contributing to this behavior.  I'm guessing that windows.onload may be better since it's only called once everything else is loaded.  The issue might be getting caused due to wierdness in element load order.

Comment: Changed to `window.onload = function()` and now it seems to execute reliably. Script 5007 error disappears in IE11 console, but it is still shows in IE10 on every refresh, although the functionality is working. Not sure if this is related as I cannot track down the div that causes the 5007 with breakpoints. It refers to a function inside jQuery library.

Comment: window.load may fire before dynamically downloaded script is completely downloaded, which may also be a factor.

Comment: Does `checkRetinaHeader()` return a promise?

Comment: @guest271314 that could be the problem and I am unsure how to implement a promise.